# Why does my ListActivity appear disabled and not respond to clicks?

Tags: android

**UPDATE:** I found that this is simply due to the default theme set for API 19. Very frustrating to spend hours chasing it down.
in styles.xml, theme is set to android:Theme.Light Frankly, it is a poor style - unreadable and widget appears disabled!

[image: screenshot of list activity appearing disabled]

MyListActivity extends ListActivity and its adapter is a list adapter that extends BaseAdapter.
However, the list items appear disabled with the text barely visible and indeed, the overridden onListItemClick() was not being called. From a SO answer by Ewoks, I set

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and I am able to click on it. However, the list appears disabled with the text barely visible.

The list item XML is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="first line of message..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/on_off"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/repeatDays"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="on/off" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/repeatDays"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/end_time"
        android:text="S M T W T F S"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/periodic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/start_time"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/start_time"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="periodic"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/on_off"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/on_off"
        android:text="duration"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/start_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/periodic"
        android:text="start time"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/end_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start_time"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="end time"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check if you have overridden public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
in your base adapter and return false

Comment: @alecnash you mean, do this? setting to return true or false makes no difference. ` /* (non-Javadoc)
  * @see android.widget.BaseAdapter#isEnabled(int)
  */
 @Override
 public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
  return true; 
  // super.isEnabled(position);
 }

Comment: see update for solution